# Does being mounted on a horse make fast traveling faster?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any difference between:

1. Fast travel with no horse.
2. Fast travel with a horse you are not currently on.
3. Fast travel with a horse you are mounted on.

By difference, I mean in-game time that is consumed by the fast travel.

Comment: This should be easy to test. Pick up 2 cities. Press tab and check the time, then fast travel to the second town. Check the time again. Mount a horse and then fast travel back to the first town. Check the time again and compare.

Comment: [In TES IV: Oblivion, being mounted on a horse will improve the speed of fast traveling](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Horses).

Comment: Ha. I'd been wondering about this the entire time, and still haven't bothered to check. And now I know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no difference, whether you're on foot, on a stolen horse, on a horse you own, or near a horse you own.

Tested by fast traveling between Riften stables and Markarth stables. the trip always took 26 hours and 5 minutes.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, but only in one very specific instance: you're over-encumbered.  Otherwise, all forms of fast travel occur at the same speed.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Horses

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Carriage#Fast_Travel

Comment: That doesn't make it faster, that just makes it possible.

Comment: Wow, and that is a great reason for horses!

Comment: Any form of fast travel is faster than no fast travel.

Comment: but...how do you get up onto the horse when you're over-encumbered?

Comment: Good one! Upvoted.