# Is it more efficient to wait or is there an efficient distance to travel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For the purposes of resetting NPCs and respawning items, it can take—at most—up to [30 days (720 hours) of in-game time.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawning)

There is an option to wait and there is an option to fast travel. Each passes time. If I want to expedite the passage of time, such as in order to respawn a location, is it more efficient to wait or fast travel? If the latter, between whence and whereto? Between which two places is the most efficient?

I guess hard drive speed factors in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tested on my system (Windows 8.1 Pro, AMD Phenom II X6 1075T (3GHz), 12GB RAM, GTX780, game and OS on same SSD), character was the default character the game gives you if you use `coc` command in main menu (full iron armour equipped).

### Test results

#### Waiting

Waiting takes **22 seconds** for every **20 hours**, which would make waiting **720 hours** take **13 minutes and 12 seconds**.

#### Fast travelling

Fast travelling a long distance (Fort Dawnguard to Castle Volkihar<sup>1</sup>, including map navigation time) took **9.6 seconds** and advanced the time by **32 and a half hours**. That would make "waiting" **720 hours** take a little under **4 minutes** in total.

**This makes travelling much faster option.**

#### Waiting with `tfc` (PC only)

On PC you can use `tfc` console command to go into free camera mode. While in this mode, *waiting is a lot faster* with **20 hours** taking just over **2 seconds!** This way of waiting is the fastest option by far. This makes waiting **720 hours** take just **a minute and a half!**

---

Slower processors and hard drives most likely favour waiting more, as do heavily modded games.

<sup>1</sup>I chose these 2 locations, because they're on the opposite sides of the map making the distance very long and both locations are surrounded by quickly loaded terrain, one being surrounded by water and the other by mountains.

Comment: Waiting while using tfc seems to count as sleeping.

Answer (score 3):

The longest fast-travel route, Markarth-Riften, takes 24 hours wearing light armour.

Which is quicker depends on how long the loading screen lasts. Waiting 24 hours takes about 30 seconds so if you can open the menu, fast travel and get through the loading screen faster, it's faster to do that.

Comment: Huh, I didn't think of type of armour affecting travel time, I guess because I never wear heavy and I often don't mind being naked.

Comment: @NiteCyper I believe [armor doesn't have anything to do with fast travel speed](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/51147/4797).

Comment: @galacticninja Those answers don't mention armour, just horses and overencumbrance. Though there is an implication that they may have tested armour. You sort-of reduced your credibility by linking that. X)