# Is there a way to permanently disable the orbiting idle camera?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I don't do anything for too long, the camera will enter third-person view and circle me. It returns to my normal view once I interact with the game. Is there a way to permanently toggle this camera behaviour off?

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, without the help of any mods or in-game add-ons, it is **not possible** to permanently disable the orbiting idle camera. There are 2 other methods, however, that you may find especially useful:

- **Toggle the Freefly camera**

Simply do so by entering the command `TFC` into the console. This will switch your camera mode into freefly and "disable" the idle camera.

- **[Delay when idle will be turned off](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/544954-disable-camera-zooming-out-when-standing-around-for-a-while/)**

> Add this to the bottom of skyrim.ini located at (on Windows 7)
>   \Documents\My Games\Skyrim\
>
> [Camera]
>
> ; Rotating camera when idle can not be turned off, but
>   delayed.
>
> ; 120 seconds is default. Here we go with half an hour:
>
> fAutoVanityModeDelay=1800.0000

Here are a few of the possible and known side effects that have occured when idling while "TFC-ed":

> Having an issue though, I was using one of the break dancing
>   animations on my PC and companion- NPC (Lydia). It was a wilderness
>   area at night with snow falling (near a fort).  I "TFC'ed" via the
>   console and zoomed it out a good bit then left it idle (had company
>   over). When finally getting back to my computer, I had noticed a few
>   things: my player character had become semi-transparent. This was
>   fixed when I toggled out of TFC command again, however 3 things
>   happened at this point -
>
> 1) the forced-3rd person angle was locked in and I still cannot zoom
>   in or out as I would normally with the mouse wheel.
>
> 2) there were some bizarre shadow-artifacts flashing at different
>   angles (never had this issue). I reloaded to a previous save and these
>   slowly disappeared when utilizing vanilla animations in-game.
>
> 3) and this is a strange one, the loading screen objects became
>   "burned" into fog type effects so that the semi-invisible object was
>   static as it was when the loading screen had finished (keeping its
>   true scale as the actual loading screen).
>
> I really feel this was a conflict with a lighting mod (using latest
>   Realistic Lighting mod - Vision option) and the TFC command.

Source: [LINK](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/593117-fores-new-idles-in-skyrim-fnis/page-16)

Comment: I think using the wait option while `tfc` is on causes the wait to count as sleep. Do you know if idling while `tfc` is on has any such side effects too?

Comment: @NiteCyper See the above edit

Comment: Tried and it checks out. `tfc` had no side-effects. However, I found another answer. I may not accept either (for now).

Comment: @NiteCyper I do hope that you understand that these "side-effects" as you call them, often do not occur for everyone. Such side effects are usually situational and there are many factors that could potentially affect it. If tfc has not side effects for you, then it has no side-effects, for you. The ones that I listed above were merely bugs that occurred. If TFC-ing were to truly have a recurring bug, then Bethesda would have fixed it a long time ago. This is also the reason why I had not entered the possible side-effects that may happen in the first place as I felt that they were unnecessary.

Comment: However, as you requested for me to do so, I felt obliged to give it.

Comment: (1) The first half of your paragraph sounds like it's arguing like the "absence of evidence" aphorism, but the latter half sounds opposite. I was skeptical because I used to think `tfc` didn't have any side-effects until I tried [waiting](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182608/is-it-more-efficient-to-wait-or-is-there-an-efficient-distance-to-travel#comment247290_182612) while it was toggled on. (2) Re: "Bethesda would have fixed it a long time ago": LOL. (3) I was impressed and appreciate the extra research that you put in. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `tfc` console command works and doesn't have side-effects (except that saving will save the `tfc` state), but I also found something else. The "[Better INI Tweaks for Skyrim](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/50692/?)" (BITS) mod includes the option to "Disable the auto vanity camera mode". I looked into it and found the corresponding lines:

> ; Disables the automatic rotating 3rd person camera which activates after your character is idle for
>   ; too long.  If AutoVanityMode is enabled, other variables control the delay (in seconds) before
>   ; it activates, the increment of the camera rotation, and the zoom level of the camera.
>   `#bDisableAutoVanityMode=0`
>   `#fAutoVanityModeDelay=120`
>   `#fAutoVanityIncrement=0.0100`
>   `#fDefaultAutoVanityZoom=300`
>   `bDisableAutoVanityMode=1`

> ; Install to \Skyrim\Data and the tweaks in this file will override any of the same tweaks from
>   ; the Skyrim.ini file, typically found in C:\Users[USERNAME]\Documents\My Games\Skyrim.
>   ;
>   ; Any line in an INI file that begins with a semicolon [;] or a hashtag [#] is interpreted as a
>   ; comment to be read by humans and is ignored by the game.